# Check if a string is a valid date using DateTime.TryParse

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `DateTime.TryParse()` function to check if a particular string is a valid datetime not depending on any cultures.

To my surprise , the function returns `true` for even strings like "1-1", "1/1" .etc.

How can I solve this problem?

Update:

Does it mean, if I want to check if a particular string is valid datetime, I need a huge array of formats??  There will be different combinations , I believe.

Even there are lots of date separator ( '.' , '/' , '-', etc..) depending on the culture, it will be difficult for me to define an array of format to check against .

Basically, I want to check if a particular string contains  AT LEAST  day(1 through 31 or 01 through 31),month(1 through 12 or 01 through 12) and year(yyyy or yy) in any order, with any date separator , what will be the solution?

So, if the value includes any parts of time, it should return true too.
I could NOT be able to define a array of format.

Comment: You start by defining what a solution would be. I could see both of those being interpreted as January 1st of the current year. Problem solved.

Comment: Exactly, Wood. I'm NOT sure how this works , but strings like "1-1000" will give you January 1st , 1000.

Comment: What is the problem? By design, a date without a year returns this year as default...

What do you need to do?

Comment: @Laurence, how does this function assume which part of the input string is a year then??

Comment: I don't know how it works internally, but it's logical to assume that if there are two numbers, and both are less than 31, that one is the month and one is the day. It would then give the year to be this year. Just like if I told you "I did it on February 10", you'd assume I was talking about this year...

What is it you are trying to do? Using TryParseExact() might give you what you need...

Comment: @Laurence then if I say "1", will you assume I'm talking about the 1st day of the current month?? If your answer is "yes", then if I input any integers between "0" to "31" , this tryparse function should return true. 
And I believe " 02 10" and "February 10" are different. If you mentioned "February" then , everybody understand you are talking about a date(month). What if I said "2" , instead?

Comment: All good points, Kai. But can you be clear about what the 'problem' is here? TryParse functions in a well defined, specified way when there's a missing year (i.e. it uses this year if the year is missing).

What functionality do you want? There are lots of suggestions below about TryParseExact, but without defining exactly what it is that you want to be able to do, it's hard to suggest what the right solution is.

Comment: @Laurence, basically, I just want a function(simple enough) whether a particular string is date (or) date+time.  To me, strings like "1-1" is definitely NOT a date. But, on the other hands, it make sense TryParse() parse this into a date as it is supposed to parse the input string into date, NOT to check if string is date or NOT.
So, all in all, I just want a function to check if input string is a date.

Comment: Got it. Then stick with the TryParseExact() answers below.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you want your dates to conform a particular format or formats then use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) otherwise that is the default behaviour of `DateTime.TryParse`

[DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx)

> This method tries to **ignore unrecognized data**, if possible, and
>   fills in **missing month, day, and year** information with the current
>   date. If s contains only a date and no time, this method assumes the
>   time is 12:00 midnight. If s includes a date component with a
>   two-digit year, it is converted to a year in the current culture's
>   current calendar based on the value of the Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax
>   property. Any leading, inner, or trailing white space character in s
>   is ignored.

If you want to confirm against multiple formats then look at [DateTime.TryParseExact Method (String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) overload. Example from the same link:

```
string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                   "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                   "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
string[] dateStrings = {"5/1/2009 6:32 PM", "05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                        "5/1/2009 6:32:00", "05/01/2009 06:32", 
                        "05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM", "05/01/2009 06:32:00"}; 
DateTime dateValue;

foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
{
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
      Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       Converted '5/1/2009 6:32 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 PM. 
//       Converted '05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:05 PM. 
//       Converted '5/1/2009 6:32:00' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM. 
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM. 
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 PM. 
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32:00' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM.
```

Comment: @Kai, for your update, it would be difficult *(I am not saying impossible YET)*, but you have to have some kind of rules for your string, REGEX comes as a possible solution but I don't think even that would work with all types of strings.

Comment: Thanks, Habib. I guess so. I will accept this as an answer if nobody comes up with the solution.

Answer (score 19):

Use  `DateTime.TryParseExact()` if you want to match against a specific date format

```
 string format = "ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a date");
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
[TestCase("11/08/1995", Result= true)]
[TestCase("1-1", Result = false)]
[TestCase("1/1", Result = false)]
public bool IsValidDateTimeTest(string dateTime)
{
    string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy" };
    DateTime parsedDateTime;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime);
}
```

Simply  specify the date time formats that you wish to accept in the array named *formats*.

Answer (score 6):

So this question has been answered but to me the code used is not simple enough or complete. To me this bit here is what I was looking for and possibly some other people will like this as well.

```cs
string dateString = "198101";

if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out DateTime Temp) == true)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

The output is stored in `Temp` and not needed afterwards, `datestring` is the input string to be tested.

Comment: This is more what I want but I can't get this line working - it doesn't like the "out DateTime Temp" bit. Does this work with 4.5.2 framework or higher?

Comment: I am using .NET Core 1.6 currently and the above code worked.

Comment: @Deathstalker: Please have a look at my suggestion. I had the same problem as you - the accepted answer is way to elaborate for my purposes, but your answer was missing a bit of explanations.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to create a method to validate that the text is of Date type.

```
public bool IsDateTime(string date)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(date)) return false;
    return DateTime.TryParse(date, out DateTime dateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I want to check if a particular string contains AT LEAST day(1 through 31 or 01 through 31),month(1 through 12 or 01 through 12) and year(yyyy or yy) in any order, with any date separator , what will be the solution? 
>   So, if the value includes any parts of time, it should return true too. I could NOT be able to define a array of format.

When I was in a similar situation, here is what I did:

1. Gather all the formats my system is expected to support.
2. Looked at what is common or can be generalize.
3. Learned to create REGEX (It is an investment of time initially but pays off once you create one or two on your own). Also do not try to build REGEX for all formats in one go, follow incremental process.
4. I created REGEX to cover as many format as possible.
5. For few cases, not to make REGEX extra complex, I covered it through DateTime.Parse() method.
6. With the combination of both Parse as well as REGEX i was able to validate the input is correct/as expected.

This http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13255/Validation-with-Regular-Expressions-Made-Simple
was really helpful both for understanding as well as validation the syntax for each format.

My 2 cents if it helps....

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
    txtPaymentSummaryBeginDate.Text.Trim(),
    "MM/dd/yyyy", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

It throws an exception if the input string is not in proper format, so in the `catch` section you can `return false;`