# How to get last Day of the Month from a date string in C#?

Tags: c#

How would I find the last day of current month stated in the String?

E.g. if the string was "January 2018" how would I record 31/01/2018 as the date

Currently it defaults to the first of the month:

```
string nextEventDateString = "January 2018"
DateTime tempDate;

if (DateTime.TryParse(nextEventDateString, out tempDate))
{
    cRecord.ComplianceDate = tempDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    cRecord.NotifyDate = tempDate.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    cRecord.WarningDate = tempDate.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First parse the string to `DateTime` , later **add one month and subtract one day** from the date, it will give you the last day for the month like:

```
string dateString = "January 2018";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime lastDateForMonth = dt.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

*As a side note, It appears you are keeping a string representation of `DateTime` in your object properties. It would be better to keep `DateTime` instead of `string`. Use string representation in formatting/presentation. IMO. Also continue using `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` with a format, as it will save you from the exception in case of failed parsing.*

Comment: thank you - in the end I used DateTime.TryParseExact as the string always changes.

Comment: @joeMarsden, you are welcome. You can also pass an array of custom formats in `Datetime.TryParseExact` to comply with multiple formats. You may see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16075279/961113)

Answer (score 2):

Using this:

```
var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2018, 01);
```

You will get the number of days for the January of 2018. Then 
you could build your datetime like below:

```
DateTime lastDayForMonth = new DateTime(year, month, days-1);
```

where in place of `year` and `month` you will place the year and the month you are interested in.

In any case, you have to parse your string first and create a valid `DateTime`, in order you get the year, `dt.Year` and the month `dt.Month` (`dt` is the parsed date time string).

Comment: In your first code block, you hardcore the year and month, but in the second, you use `year` and `month`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson thanks for your comment dude, but as I have stated at the bottom of my answer, in any case the string should be first parsed. I just showed the usage of this specific method. If it is not clear, I am sorry. Let me know and I will correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```