# Is there any way user can disable server side validation in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have web application in which user can enter date of birth only from one form. I have asp.net validators as well as server side validation methods that are called before save method is called.

Following is the code for server side validation:

```
 private bool ValidateData(out string error)
    {
        error = string.Empty;
        //Validate Date of Birth
        TextBox txtDOB = (TextBox)clientinfo.FindControl("txtDOB");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDOB.Text.Trim()))
        {
            DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text.Trim());

            if (dob >= DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                error = error + "Client can not be less than 7 years and greater than 100 years old.";
            }
            else if (dob < DateTime.Now.Date && (DateTime.Now.Date.Year - dob.Year) > 100)
            {
                error = error + "Client can not be less than 7 years and greater than 100 years old.";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            error = error + "Please enter date of birth.";
        }

        return error.Length > 0 ? false : true;
    }
```

Some how there is one record with date of birth as '07/19/2045' (MM/DD/YYYY). Every time I test, I can see validation is working.

I can disable clint side validation from browser. But is there any way we can disable server side validation?..

I need to know how a wrong entry happened in order to prevent any future issues. 
Please let me know if there is any way user can override server validation or I am doing something wrong in my method.

Comment: have you tested the code stepping through it using the wrong entry..? perhaps you have some logical error.. also you need to have a method of checking the DateTime of a string is valid so initially your logic is incorrect.. I would personally check the value in the textbox if it's not even a valid date show a message and return here is a link with some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075159/check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-using-datetime-tryparse

Comment: Is 7/19/2045 the wrong record?  2045 is less than 100 years from now (currently 2015).....

Comment: @MethodMan, Yes I haves tested the code.. And it works fine. I will also add a validation for proper date format.

Comment: @Tim, I am also checking if date is greater than today's date, 'dob >= DateTime.Now.Date', so according to which 2045 is greater year and it should not be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user can't modify the server, the error more than likely exist in your conversion from a `String` to `DateTime`.  You could try the following approach:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out date))
     if(date <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-7) && date >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100))
         Console.WriteLine("Valid Date");
```

You would need to add your `else` statements to implement those errors, you may have to play with the comparison, but that should work for a nice starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Greg.. I will use your approach.. however first condition 'dob >= DateTime.Now.Date', should not allow '7/19/2045' as a valid date.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you wanted, so it forces the person to be under a hundred and over seven.  You would need to tweak the comparison, like I noted.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks.. I will use this approach.. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to me it will not be possible to disable the server side validation as I could not see any config entry which could stop the entry into this code and I think only way to handle this issue will be copy the dlls onto the local system and try out the various scenarios. Regarding the wrong entry you can do the same input in another machine or a sample console app to see which part of the validation is failing for it. Hope this helps.