# Is there reliable method to validate argument for DateTime::modify() for relative format

Tags: php, datetime

[PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) claims that `DateTime::modify()` and `strtotime()` both should return `false` in case of error, but I'm getting this:

```
> php -r 'var_dump(time(), strtotime("-1 week"), strtotime("-1 wesdek"), (new DateTime())->modify("-1 weeekc"));'
int(1533556632)
int(1532951832)
int(1533560232)
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-08-06 11:57:12.797259"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}

> php -v
PHP 7.2.7 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

If `wesdek` and `weeekc` are valid strings, what are they meaning?

P.S. I've seen [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899347/validate-string-input-for-datetimemodify), but here I've shown that obvious methods from there aren't always working…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this, I thought about something like

```
function isModifyArgumentValidRelative (string $modifyString)
{
    $now = new DateTime();
    $notNow = clone $now;
    @$modifyResult = $notNow->modify("-{$modifyString}");
    if (false === $modifyResult || $notNow == $now) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Seems like it works, except `0 seconds` or `0 minutes` and so on, of course :)