# Identify Time values and format

Tags: .net, vb.net

I can receive data from a SQL database and use the following simple functionality to format dates

```
If IsDate(item.Text) Then
    item.Text = CDate(item.Text).ToShortDateString
End If
```

Is there an equivalent for time values so I can just display hours and minutes? Something like

```
If IsTime(item.Text) Then
    item.Text = item.Text.ToString("hh:mm")
End If
```

Comment: a `Date` object can contain time values too - so you can use the same function ... this might of course indicate that you don't really want to do that (it's strange anyway that you replace your date with a string ...)

Comment: `data from a SQL database` which database - they all use SQL.  that code is also well after the db has been read

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you in identifying and parsing the text to a `Date`, returning `Nothing` if the parsing was not possible (thus: not a date):

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets the date given a series of predefined formats, as shown in this post:
''' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075159/check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-using-datetime-tryparse
''' </summary>
Private Function TryGetDate(dateAsString As String) As Date?
    Dim formats As String() = {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt",
"M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"}
    Dim dateValue As Date
    If DateTime.TryParseExact(dateAsString, formats, New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue) Then
        Return dateValue
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Then, with the help of `String.Format` you can convert this date into the format you want (in your case: `HH:mm`). This is an example of how it works toghether:

```
Date? time = TryGetDate(item.Text)
If time IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim outputText = String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", time)
End If
```

Comment: @Carsten Reading the post I did not get the impression he was asking for `IsTime`. Re-reading the title I realize that it might be likely, but you will agree that his description looks like "I have this piece of code that works, and I want something like this other piece of code". But ok, fair enough.

Comment: yes exactly and there is no `IsTime` function - you are right that `ToString("...` here is a problem also but this is easily solved with `CDate(item.Text).ToString("...` instead

Comment: I'm just asking you to check if your code compiles and runs - once you made sure I'll glady upvote it - till then it's just not helping as it's wrong

Comment: @Carsten Added the `IsTime` part and a working example that behaves as expected.

Comment: well it's still not as expected (obviously the OP want to check `item.Text` not a random constant and the now obsolete `if time IsNot Nothing` ... but at least it'll probably compile/run

Comment: @Carsten I thought it was clear that my example (`"5/1/2009 6:32 PM"`) was the equivalent of `item.Text`. But seeing it is not, i am going to edit the answer. Thanks for the feedback. I don't quite understand why you are labeling `if time IsNot Nothing` as "obsolete", it is necessary for the code to run as exepected.

Comment: Just to clarify I am returning a [time] (7) value from SQL so this would be a  TimeSpan value wouldn't it?

Comment: @PaulStevens From your question I gathered that your input was a string (this is what in your code you named as `item.Text`). If this is the case, could you please give us an example of such `item.Text`? Otherwise you could give us more information about the root problem so we can understand it better.

Comment: @Xavier Peña I am returning a value from a SQL table which is stored as a [time] (7) datatype and it is being put into a GridView. I want to use a For Each loop to identify which values are TimeSpan values and then format them in the format "HH:MM" (24 hour clock) so they appear in this format when the GridView is exported to Excel.

Comment: @PaulStevens If your item is already TimeSpan, `itemAsTimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm")` should work.  And if you want to identify if your `item` is of type `TimeSpan`; `Dim t As Type = item.GetType()` and then `if( t = typeof(TimeSpan) )`.

Comment: @Xavier Peña if( t = typeof(TimeSpan) ) ? is that C#?