# How TryParseExact method works in multiple format array

Tags: c#, sql, excel

i have a question about how thetryparseexact method works.

as have assignment where i need to upload the excel data to sql serever. where i need to convert the datetime column in sql from excel. but i dont have standard format column in EXCEL. so using tryparse exact.  but how it differentiate the 
 dd and mm in normal string  for example : 10/01/2016 how it differentiate it as dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy.

i am using the below link for reference

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075159/check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-using-datetime-tryparse)

advance thanks for answers.

Comment: `mm` stands for minute use `MM`

Comment: hi un-lucky thanks for your answer. sorry but my format is MM/dd/yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy  but how tryparseexact method differentiate the given sting is in this format.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *voting* for both possible formats and then analyzing the votes cast:

```
  // collect all the datetime values in the Excel sheet(s)
  String[] data = new String[] { "01/02/2000", "25/08/2007", "09/10/2010" };
  DateTime dt;

  // then analyze them:
  int votesForDayMonth = data
    .Count(item => DateTime.TryParseExact(item, 
                                          "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                          DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                                          out dt));

  int votesForMonthDay = data
    .Count(item => DateTime.TryParseExact(item, 
                                          "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                          DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                                          out dt));

  if (votesForDayMonth == votesForMonthDay) {
    // Ambiguity, unlucky you
  }
  else if (votesForDayMonth >= data.Length) {
    // dd/MM/yyyy order: all data can be parsed as dd/MM/yyyy but not as MM/dd/yyyy
  }
  else if (votesForMonthDay >= data.Length) {
    // MM/dd/yyyy order: all data can be parsed as MM/dd/yyyy but not as dd/MM/yyyy
  }
  else if (votesForDayMonth > votesForMonthDay) {
    // probably dd/MM/yyyy order
  }
  else {
    // probably MM/dd/yyyy order
  }
```

In many *practical* cases when you have *enough clear data* you can find out the format. In the code above it's `"dd/MM/yyyy order"`