# Is it possible in C# to check if a given date format string contains just a date format or time format?

Tags: c#, datetime

For example. I have some mixed date and time format strings..

```
"date1": "dd/MM/yyyy",
"date2": "yyyy MM yyyy",
"date3": "h:mmtt",
"date4": "h:mmtt"
```

I need to check whether each of these is a time or date format. I know I can do some wizardry with string checking if it contains 'yyyy' etc. but that just feels wrong and would be open to error. Is there any way to check if a given DateTime format results in just the time being displayed or just the date?

Just to be clear I'm not interested in verifying a given date against a format or that a given date is actually a date, I'm only interested in identifying if a string DateTime format would result in just the time portion being displayed or just the date portion being displayed, if it was applied to any DateTime value.

Many thanks

Stewart

Comment: Also was thinking could have a hard-coded arbitrary date and time and try and parse them with the given format but again this just feels wrong

Comment: You can look into this Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075159/check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-using-datetime-tryparse

Comment: The first two are DateTime, the next two are TimeSpan.  Use the [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) overload that lets you pass an array of acceptable formats.  TimeSpan has an overload like that as well, use it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with something along the lines of:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum DateFormatStringKind
{
    HasNone = 0,
    HasDate = 1 << 0,
    HasTime = 1 << 1,
    HasBoth = HasDate | HasTime
}

public static DateFormatStringKind DescribeFormatString(string s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    DateTime d = new DateTime(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1); // DateTime will all non-default values
    DateTime d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(d.ToString(s, provider), s, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

    DateFormatStringKind result = DateFormatStringKind.HasNone;

    if (d2.Date.Ticks != 0)
        result |= DateFormatStringKind.HasDate;

    if (d2.TimeOfDay != TimeSpan.Zero)
        result |= DateFormatStringKind.HasTime;

    return result;
}
```

```cs
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

Console.WriteLine(DescribeFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy", culture));
Console.WriteLine(DescribeFormatString("yyyy MM yyyy", culture));
Console.WriteLine(DescribeFormatString("h:mmtt", culture));
Console.WriteLine(DescribeFormatString("dd h:mmtt", culture));
Console.WriteLine(DescribeFormatString("'literal'", culture));
```

```
HasDate
HasDate
HasTime
HasBoth
HasNone
```

It converts a date with all non-default fields into a string using the format string and then back using the same format string, and then checks what fields survived the conversion.

If there was no date component in the pattern, the "date" part will be `0001-01-01`, which is the zero date (zero ticks from the point 0). The `NoCurrentDateDefault` flag ensures that the current date is not used instead.

If there was no time component in the pattern, the time will reset to midnight (`TimeSpan.Zero` from midnight).

If there was at least one component of the date pattern (either year, month or day), the respective field will become `2`, which is greater than the default `1` for the date fields, so it will be detected regardless of what component that was.

If there was at least one component in the time pattern (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds), it will become `1`, which is greater than the default `0` for the time fields, so it will again be detected regardless of what component it was.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg, I've put this as accepted answer - ideally I was hoping there was something that could be done with some DateTime formatting wizardry without having to actually use an arbitrary date, however it seems clear this isn't possible so I think your answer is the best approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Blingers It's not an arbitrary date, it's a carefully selected date that has all required properties, and it's the same each time. Yes, you can create a comprehensive parser of the formatting string, probably look into the [source code of `ToString()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1ecc4a05169eccb8,references) for inspiration, but it's probably not going to worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in that I know of for this.

There are two methods you could use, both of which you have mentioned already.

The first is to parse against an arbitrary test date-time. This has been covered by GSerg's answer, but in brief, you essentially create a dummy date, then parse it to string and back using your format string. Obviously your test time should have a time other than 00:00, otherwise you still won't be able to tell; and it should also have a date other than "today" or "January 1, 0001" (see [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)).

The second option is to check against the full set of date-time format string variables (see [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)) - so, something like this (although it's subject to change in future implementations of the .NET framework):

The Date-related items are the following:

> "d" "dd" "ddd" "dddd" "g" "gg" "M" "MM" "MMM" "MMMM" "y" "yy" "yyy"
>   "yyyy" "yyyyy" "/"

The Time-related items are the following:

> "f" "ff" "fff" "ffff" "fffff" "ffffff" "fffffff" "F" "FF" "FFF" "FFFF"
>   "FFFFF" "FFFFFF" "FFFFFFF" "h" "hh" "H" "HH" "s" "ss" "t" "tt" "m"
>   "mm" ":"

The following are ambiguous, could be either - so we'll ignore these:

> "K" "z" "zz" "zzz"

this gives us the following pseudo-code:

```
If date1 contains any of (d,g,M,y,/) then date = true
If date1 contains any of (f,F,h,H,s,t,m,:) then time = true
If date && time then date-time
```

Note that this doesn't take into account the possibility of escaped (`\`) characters or string literals (`'...'`) containing one of the above characters. To resolve this you could first remove any character that comes after a backslash or between single quotes from your format string - but you may as well use regex at this point.

Comment: A date pattern may contain literals. E.g. `DateTime.Now.ToString("'Today is' dd/MM/yyyy")` will return `Today is 25/09/2019`. So looking whether a pattern contains an "m" or such may prove tricky.

Comment: agreed, it does make it more complex - I think your answer is better

Answer (score 0):

There are 864,000,000,000 `ticks in a day`. You can check `DateTime.Ticks` property to see if it evenly divisible by this number. If `Ticks` % `ticks in a day` is 0 then there is no time portion. Likewise, if `Ticks` / `ticks in a day` is 0 there is no day portion. Use `Math.DivRem` to do the division and modulus operation at once.

Here's a helper class.

```
    public class DateInfo
    {
        private const long ticksPerDay = 864000000000;
        public bool HasDate { get; private set; }
        public bool HasTime { get; private set; }
        public DateInfo(DateTime date)
        {
            long timeTicks = 0;
            var dayticks = Math.DivRem(date.Ticks, ticksPerDay, out timeTicks);
            HasDate = dayticks > 0;
            HasTime = timeTicks > 0;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{{{nameof(HasDate)}:{HasDate}, {nameof(HasTime)}:{HasTime}}}";
        }
        private static readonly DateTime testDate = DateTime.Parse("2/2/2 1:11");
        public static DateInfo GetDateInfo(string format)
        {
            var formatted = testDate.ToString(format);
            var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(formatted, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
            return new DateInfo(dt);
        }
    }
```

Tests:

```
        var MinDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        var OneHour = MinDate.AddHours(1);
        var OneDay = MinDate.AddDays(1);

        var tests = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>
        {
            { nameof(MinDate), DateTime.MinValue },
            { nameof(OneDay), OneDay },
            { nameof(OneHour), OneHour },
            { nameof(DateTime.Now), DateTime.Now },
            { nameof(DateTime.Today), DateTime.Today },
        };

        var infos = tests.Select(x =>
        {
            var dateInfo = new DateInfo(x.Value);
            return new { x.Key, dateInfo.HasDate, dateInfo.HasTime };
        });

        tests.ToList().ForEach(test =>
        {
            var dateInfo = new DateInfo(test.Value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{test.Key}: {dateInfo}");
        });
        var formatTests = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "date1", "dd/MM/yyyy" },
            { "date2", "yyyy MM dd" },
            { "date3", "h:mmtt" },
            { "date4", "hh:mmtt" }
        };
        formatTests.ToList().ForEach(test =>
        {
            var dateInfo = DateInfo.GetDateInfo(test.Value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{test.Key}: {dateInfo}");
        });
```

Result:

```
MinDate: {HasDate:False, HasTime:False}
OneDay: {HasDate:True, HasTime:False}
OneHour: {HasDate:False, HasTime:True}
Now: {HasDate:True, HasTime:True}
Today: {HasDate:True, HasTime:False}
date1: {HasDate:True, HasTime:False}
date2: {HasDate:True, HasTime:False}
date3: {HasDate:False, HasTime:True}
date4: {HasDate:False, HasTime:True}
```

Comment: The OP wants to check if the *format string* has `mm` or `dd` or `yy` or such in it, not if an instance of `DateTime` has them.

Comment: Added additional methods to allow testing the format string.

Comment: Your `testDate` is wrong because it does not include seconds and milliseconds, so if the pattern only includes those and does no include minutes and up, you will fail to detect it. You also fail to pass the culture info to `ToString`, which means the date is not guaranteed to correctly survive the roundtrip. Once you fix that, your code will look pretty much identical to mine, the only actual difference is that you are using `Math.DivRem` and I'm using `TimeSpan.Zero`.