# Decimal values recognized as DateTime instead of returning false from DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to perform a check based on a string value whether its a date or decimal but date parse always return true for decimal.

```
string val = "3.5";
DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(val);
```

It returns a valid date `3/5/2019`.

How to validate string to know its a valid date when date format is not known?

Comment: Check for decimal first? Or use `DateTime.ParseExact` if you know which formats it can/should take

Comment: You can use `TryParseExact` and specify valid date formats.

Comment: Indeed - `DateTime.Parse` tries multiple patterns. If you only want to recognize specific ones, try parsing them specifically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string is a valid date using DateTime.TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075159/check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-using-datetime-tryparse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"How to validate string to know its a valid date?"*

The issue is that `"3.5"` ***is*** considered a valid date (and also a decimal).

If you want the decimal type to always "win" (i.e. you don't want `isDate` and `isDecimal` to both be `true`), include a decimal check in your validation.

One way to do it is to use the `TryParse` methods (which return a `bool` if a string can be parsed to the type, and which sets an `out` parameter to the converted value) to determine if the string can be converted to a type, for example:

```
string val = "3.5";

// temp variables to hold parsed values
DateTime tmpDate;
decimal tmpDec;
int tmpInt;

var isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(val, out tmpDec);
var isInteger = int.TryParse(val, out tmpInt);

// When checking if it's a DateTime, make sure it's not also a decimal
var isDate = !isDecimal && DateTime.TryParse(val, out tmpDate);
```

Comment: I had already tried but 3.5 is a valid date and a valid decimal so, it does not help at all.

Comment: In the code above, `isDate` is `false` because it includes a check for `isDecimal`. Isn't that what you were asking for?

Comment: @Munawar - "3.5 is a valid date and a valid decimal "  exactly. If we, as humans, are presented with that string and no other context, *we don't know whether it was intended to be a date, a decimal or possible something else*. You can't expect a computer to magically get an answer to it.

Comment: Yes, this answer is specific to the issue, and resolves my problem although ParseExact will best fit if formats are known.

Comment: You stil have the problem when the date format is "12122019"

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras What do you mean by *"You still have the problem"*? `isDate` will still be `false` with that input as well.

Comment: @Munawar Glad it resolves the issue. Not sure what you meant by your comment, though. I thought you *didn't* know the formats? There is `TryParseExact` which can be used similarly to the code above if you do.

Answer (score 6):

Check the [official documentation on ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

If you know the exact representation you can do something like this:

```
  format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
  try {
     result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```

If you don't know it, then you are stuck with the [cultural convetions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8#Culture)

> Parse a date and time string by using the conventions of a specific culture.  Parse(String, IFormatProvider) overload (see Parsing and Cultural Conventions)

Comment: Format is not known it can be any based on user preferences.

Comment: @Munawar how will you distinguish between 1/3/2019 and 3/1/2019 in that situation?

Comment: @Athanasios, application is used for different regions and dates stored encrypted. since, user may change the date formats so don't want to mess with applying specific format although ParseExact is best fit if format is known.